# Word for naive excitement

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word that would describe how excited a child would be meeting their hero and so overcome with the excitement they cannot form coherent questions or sentences.  That the child would not understand the complexity of their hero's life.

Comment: I'll admit that a term is not coming to me.

Comment: When the child can't form coherent sentences, we may say that s/he is *overwhelmed*.  Also, an excited child can become *overexcited*.

Comment: @ aparente001  Agreed.  I was hoping there was one word that would describe both.

Comment: @KannE. That might work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[wonderstruck](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wonderstruck) (ODO)

> (of a person) experiencing a sudden feeling of awed delight or wonder.
>
> ‘A world before which one has to relearn how to look, with the large
>   wide-eyed gaze of a wonderstruck child.’

Not exactly a single word, but I offer this at the request of some rando:

> [giddy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/giddy) with excitement

They appear in a single context in the following:

**APOLLONIUS OF RHODES**

**Jason and the Argonauts**

[*Translated by* Aaron Poochigia (BOOK 1, page 10, 333-337):](https://books.google.com/books?id=F7xvDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&dq=jason%20and%20the%20argonauts%20giddy%20hero&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1v5TR3p7iAhVic98KHSLFC7gQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=jason%20and%20the%20argonauts%20giddy%20hero&f=false)

> Though crowds of **giddy** citizens had gathered round them, the
>   heroes shone like starlight between clouds. The men who watched them
>   marching under arms stood wonderstruck and muttered to each
>   other... (Emphasis added.)

---

Yes, I found the Golden Fleece. It's epic.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the child is **dazzled** by his/her hero from [dazzle](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dazzled)

> to impress deeply; astonish with delight

or a [synonym](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dazzled) of dazzled (*overawed, awestruck, dumbstruck, bowled over*)